# Form Builder for web

Tags: javascript, web-development, web-services, forms

I am looking for a form builder and of course there are tons of out there but the exceptional thing I am looking for is a package with the following features:

1. UI (drag, drop & ordering) of form elements to create a form.
2. Dynamic behaviors i.e selecting a certain field in select box should add/remove certain part/fields of form.
3. Validation (Fields required, field format i.e credit-card etc).
4. Generates JSON which stores all the information of form which can be used by a visual interpreter to create edit/view and create layout of forms.
5. Open Source (Under a license which allows editing).

I have found a tone of form builders but none of them cover all of these scenarios, I would really appreciate if you guys can help me find one. Even if it lacks one of the feature it's ok just share what you know..